# Data cannot be found in InfluxDB until several minutes after sent from java

Tags: influxdb

I'm a beginner about InfluxDB.
And I'm trying to sent data from java web application.

I set up a InfluxDB 2.4.0 on my server.
And I'm using influxdb-client-java.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.influxdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>influxdb-client-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I wrote a test like this:

```java
@Test
void sendData() {
    // Prepare
    String query = "from(bucket:\"RECORDING\") |> range(start: 0) |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] == \"counter\") |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_field\"] == \"count\")";
    List<FluxTable> list = target.query(query);
    int oldSize = list.get(0).getRecords().size();

    // Execute
    target.send(2);
    list = target.query(query);
    int newSize = list.get(0).getRecords().size();

    // Assert
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, newSize-oldSize);
}
```

```java
public void send(int data) {
    Point point = Point.measurement(measurement)
            .addField(field, data)
            .time(System.currentTimeMillis(), WritePrecision.MS);

    this.sendBlocking(point);
}
private void sendBlocking(Point point) {
    WriteApiBlocking writeApi = client.getWriteApiBlocking();
    writeApi.writePoint(point);
}
```

But the test failed because newSize is equal to oldSize.
Which means the data was not sent successfully, or the query is too soon that the data hasn't bee saved.
And I checked the data from InfluxDB GUI.

[InfluxDB GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqQJ0.png)

The time is correct, it's exact the time when I ran my test.
I kept querying, but the data wouldn't be shown after about 2 minutes later than the time I sent.
I've tried several times, each time data can be saved at last, but not until one or two minutes after the sending-data-operation.

Is it the feature of the WriteApiBlocking, or should I change some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my influxDB server is two minutes earlier than my application server, so the data cannot be queried with [past 15min] condition.

I synchronized server time and everything is ok now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).